# Pegar parâmetros da URL

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho a seguinte url: 
`http://localhost:27903/detalhes.aspx?id=3014953&stars=70`
Preciso pegar os parametros separados, id e stars, alguma dica ai já tentei de tudo, segue meu código:

```
$('tbody#corpo2').append(            
'<tr><td style="border:solid 1px #ccc; text-align:center">' + location.search.substring(4) + '</td>'
+ '<td style="border:solid 1px #ccc">' + "teste" + '</td>'
+ '<td style="border:solid 1px #ccc">' + location.search.substring(17).replace("s=", "").replace("=","") + ' </td>' + '</tr>');
});
```

Comment: Obs: o location.search.substring(4) pega tudo até o final da URL, teria como limitar pra ele pegar até o &?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desta forma é possível pegar os parâmetros enviados via GET.

```
var query = location.search.slice(1);
var partes = query.split('&');
var data = {};
partes.forEach(function (parte) {
    var chaveValor = parte.split('=');
    var chave = chaveValor[0];
    var valor = chaveValor[1];
    data[chave] = valor;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Valeu meu bruxo, deu certo, abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está como pegar todos os parâmetros e colocar num objeto:

```
//Array de parametros 'chave=valor'
var params = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

//Criar objeto que vai conter os parametros
var paramArray = {};

//Passar por todos os parametros
for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    //Dividir os parametros chave e valor
    var param = params[i].split('=');

    //Adicionar ao objeto criado antes
    paramArray[param[0]] = param[1];
}
```

Para pegar um valor: `paramArray['chave']`

Answer (score 0):

Pode pegar parametros da url  utilizando javascript.
     Utilizando a Url :http://localhost:27903/detalhes.aspx?id=3014953&stars=70  como exemplo  :

```
 <script>
        //Acessamos a funcao passando o parametros que queremos o valor do seu retorno .Ex: o parametro [stars]

 function getParameter(theParameter) {
            var params = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var p = params[i].split('=');
                if (p[0] == theParameter) {
                    return decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
                }
            }
            return false;
            }
            var valorHidSelProduto = getParameter('stars')
            alert(stars);

    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var data = url.searchParams.get("stars"); //pega o value
```

Answer (score -5):

Eu pego via PHP e transmito ao JavaScript

```
<script>
Valor = <? $_GET[Valor] ?>;
Parametro_GET = <? $_GET[Parametro_GET] ?>;
<script>
```

Comment: Isso funciona apenas se a página for PHP, que não é o caso.